# Text field that allow text and draggable and sortable tags in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, tags

I want to make a text field the allows **text** as well as **tags drag and drop** from outside.
Tags should also be **sortable** inside the field like it is the image linked below. I have searched over the internet looking for a similar implementation but couldn't find one. Any help will be much appreciated.

[image: sample image]

Comment: Anything found?

Comment: Did you found anything?